# Converting a .dgp file

Tags: image

I have a (many) .dgp files, which is an image file that I can't open with any of the usual editors. I do know that it's a fairly normal image file though, not encoded or anything like that. Just that the headers or whatnot are not incorrect. I don't really know much about this.

Is there any program that could assist me in taking part the image file and seeing the insides, or perhaps even better, automate the process for me.

Thanks.

Edit: There probably isn't a ready built converter that can be used. What I'm more looking for is some sort of app that can read image data even without the correct headers.

Edit again:

I apologize for being slow with the updates, it's only been one day! You don't have to vote me down!

Here's an example:

http://uploading.com/files/F3O7FXYE/BG00.DGP.html

My DGP file is an image extracted from an old Sega Saturn game. My assignment is to figure out how to get it to a usable form even though most apps do not recognize it.

file returns: data by the way.

Thanks everyone.

Edit3:

Thanks for helping Dave Rigby, here are two more sample files:
http://uploading.com/files/96WFWQBB/BG03.DGP.html
http://uploading.com/files/KXE16TRT/BG06B.DGP.html

I'm not certain what dimensions these are, sorry. But they're likely to be the same, but may not be.

Comment: Hi! So some other technical details might be helpful to us so that we can help find a solution. So:

1. What is a .dgp file - do you have an article/link that describes the format?

2. Where are they used? What program produced the dgp files? What do you use to view them (or what have you used to view them in the past?)

3. Do you have an example .dgp file you could show us - maybe we could figure out the format.

4. What did you mean by a "fairly normal image file"? Is it encoded like a .bmp file? (all images have to have some sort of encoding - some way that they describe the pixels.)

Comment: Are these dynamometer graphs? rascher is correct - it really would be necessary to have an example file and as much information about it as is available, such as height, width, etc.

Comment: Can you give us some more info on the files? For example, if you are running on a *ix OS, the 'file' command may give some basic information on the type of file this is.

Comment: How can he offer a 150pt bounty when he has only 11 pts? I thought a bounty was offered from the user's own points?..

Comment: I had more points of course, but I gave it up to offer a bounty.

Comment: Ok, so I've had a look at the file you posted, but it doesn't look like any standard file format (no great surprise). There's definately some data in there, and it's in a pretty regular pattern so I can believe it's an image encoded in some form. Any chance you could give us any more information about it - e.g. what dimensions it is? 
Also, another example would be useful to see what's the same and what varies between two different images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found a Japanese package called ninix-aya whose source code [appears](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#XvWZnU8Tai8/ninix-aya-3.8.4/lib/ninix/pix.py&q=create_pixbuf_from_DGP_file&l=40) to be able to open DGP files. My Japanese is non-existent, so I have no clue what this program is or what it does, but it should be possible to extract the functions which operate on BGP files and open them yourself (assuming these are the same type of files that you have).

**Edit:**

Ok, I've had a play around with the three files you posted. I had a look at them with `hexdump` and they all have virtually the same 11 bytes: Files BG00.DGP and BG06B.DGP have the exactly the same first 11 bytes and in BG03.DGP the 5th byte is `7f` instead of `ff`:

```
06 30 02 00 ff 44 43 01 40 00 e0
```

I'm guessing this is some form of header, but I can't see how it's encoded.

The remaining data looks like some kind of bitmap image, but I can't see exactly what it is - there is a definite geometric pattern in BG00.DGP; the other two files seen less ordered. Looking at it using `display` (from ImageMagick) I can believe they are images, but there's quite a few variables to guess at - pixal format, colour/greyscale, image size, endian etc.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mean dpg did you?
http://www.aimersoft.com/dpg-converter.html
is a converter for dpg video files never heard of dgp, and all the google results i found where just misspellings of dpg.

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty similar to .DG2 files (also seen in Sega Saturn games), except they are compressed with a variant of [LZSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Storer%E2%80%93Szymanski).

The file has a four-byte header, which is the length of the decompressed data stored as a little-endian integer. After the header is the compressed data.

I believe [this code](https://github.com/luikore/lzss/blob/master/src/lzss.c) can decompress it if you redefine `THRESHOLD` to 3 instead of 2.

After you decompress the data, you'll see another header. This header is six bytes long. The first two bytes are always `0x44 0x43`. The next two bytes are the width of the image, stored as a big-endian integer. The next two bytes are the height of the image, also stored as a big-endian integer.

The image data is 15-bit RGB.